# iPhone calendar/todo list app with easily enterable and snoozable reminders?

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, reminders

There are a lot of reminder/calendar/todo list apps, and it's hard to make sense of all of them.  Hoping someone can recommend one that meets the following criteria:

1. Reminders are as easy to enter as possible.  Ideally one screen where I type a quick description, and enter the date and time that I want the alert.
2. Reminders must be easily snoozable, **for an arbitrary (or near arbitrary) amount of time**.   By this I mean:  The phone vibrates and the reminder pops up.  I then have the option to dismiss the reminder, or to snooze it, and (extremely important) I can choose (right there, not just a default setting within the app) how long to snooze it for.  I should be able to either type in a number of minutes to snooze it for, or select from a list (e.g. 10/20/30/40/50/60 minutes, etc.)

Big bonus points if I can enter reminders via the web and have them automatically synced to the phone.

Nice to have:  Daily view (i.e. show all reminders for a given day)

Does something like this exist?

Comment: Not sure it satisfies all of your requirements, but how about [Due](http://www.dueapp.com/)? It also says there are some [snooze interval limitations](http://www.dueapp.com/faq.html#snoozelimitations)

Comment: Thanks - it looks nice, but those snooze limitations are a deal-breaker unfortunately.  And wait, an app can only display 64 notifications?  (Per what, exactly?)  Guess I may not be getting an iPhone after all, since this is close to the #1 thing I want a smartphone for...

Comment: I'm a user of Due, and it has variable length snooze intervals, even from the lock screen.  It's not really designed to hold a large number of things;  more to bug you about a small number of important things until you do them.  I have 7 items in there, and have had as high as 12'ish.  There is a minimum interval:  10 minutes on OSX and I can't remember if it's 5 or 10 or iOS.